# Connecting two sphere with a cylinder

Tags: modeling

I want connect the two shperes with a cylinder.

Using the cylinder passes through the centers of the two sphere.

Are there any procedures to do that?
[image]

Comment: oh this is Blender

Comment: oh this is Blender? Yes you can easily connect two spheres, can you be more specific about your problem and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to connect two spheres with a cylinder:

- Create a cube, then in Edit mode, <kbd>W</kbd> *Subdivide Smooth*, and increase the subdivision with the parameters on the bottom of the <kbd>T</kbd> menu
- Select a square and <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Circle*
- Make a hole, then extrude to create a circle inside the circle (<kbd>E</kbd>)
- Duplicate your sphere and rotate the duplicate
- Select the two holes and <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge*

After that you can add a Subdivision modifier, add edge loops to make the edge loops sharper, etc...

[image]

Comment: Note that subdivided cubes aren't exactly spheres due to the poles at the corners; apply the subdivision modifier and add a Cast modifier > Cast to sphere to actually make it a sphere. This can be done with a fairly low subdivision modifier; afterwards, another (unapplied) subdiv modifier can be added to smooth the sphere. Then again, why not use a uv sphere to begin with?

Comment: yes you can begin with UV Sphere  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ad Sphere > go to Edit mode (Tab) > Duplicate (Shift+D) > Select two Edge Loops (ALt+Shift+RMB) > Search (Space bar) "Bridge" > Enter

[image]